# Text vanishing in Outlook.com only

Tags: html, email, outlook

I am having a big problem with an email I am sending, and I am not sure what is causing it. A majority of the text will vanish, but not the text in the  tag. This is only happening in Outlook.com and not in outlook, gmail, etc. I have sent a variation of this email last week and it worked previously, and I have no idea what is causing it to break now. Any help would be great.

[image]

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="text-align:left; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333; font-size: 15px; line-height:22px; line padding-left: 5px;" valign="middle">
                <font color="#333333">Dear~FORENAME~,<br>
                <br>
                As a previous customer, you&#8217; ll already know that <i>Red</i>is full of inspiring features about the best things in life: fashion, beauty, travel, and most of all, the things that matter to you.<br>
                <br>
                <font size="+0.5"><b>Great reasons to subscribe:</b></font></font>
                <ul style="padding-left:5px;">
                    <li><font color="#333333"><b>FREE</b>goodie bag worth over &#163; 50<font size="-4">&#8224;</font></font></li>
                    <li style="list-style: none"><font color="#333333"></font></li>
                    <li><font color="#333333"><b>ONLY &#163; 1</b>an issue (usually &#163; 4.30)</font></li>
                    <li><font color="#333333"><b>MASSIVE SAVING</b>of over &#163; 19</font></li>
                    <li><font color="#333333">Continue to <b>SAVE 30&#37;</b> after your introductory offer</font></li>
                </ul><font color="#333333">I look forward to sending you the first issue of your <i>Red</i>subscription. <a href="" style="color:#d10c08">Subscribe to Red now!</a><br>
                <br>
                <br></font>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td rowspan="2" valign="top"><img align="left" src="images/ed-photo-RED.jpg" width="96px"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding:0 0 10px 10px; text-align:left; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333; font-size: 16px; vertical-align:top">Yours sincerely,<br>
                            <br>
                            <img align="left" src="images/sarah.png" width="120px"><br>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            Sarah Bailey<br>
                            Editor-in-chief &nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table><i>P.S. This special offer is only available for a limited time and must close on 9th June 2017, so subscribe now.</i>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: please reformat the code.

Comment: Sorry is that better?

Answer (score 0):

I know what it was now

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="text-align:left; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333; font-size: 15px; line-height:22px; line padding-left: 5px;" valign="middle">
```

It was the extra word line before padding-left: 5px. I feel quite foolish.